# Strings in Excel for times tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet, substr

I am new here, i wanted to ask a question.

I am trying to write up the 5 times tables on excel using strings, I know i can do this easily using a table formula. I wanted the table to look like " 5*1 = 5"

So far i have managed to get a formula like

```
(5&" * "&A1)
```

A1 being 1

how can i go about putting in an = sign without it bringing up an error command? 
Also is there any way i can do all this without having to go A1, A2...

Can i put in a loop or anything?

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=5&"*"&Row()&"="&5*Row()
```

This will take the row that the formula is in as the multiple though, for example if this is in cell `A1` on the worksheet then it will do `5*1` and in cell `A6` it will do `5*6`.

Answer (score 0):

Use formula:

```
="5*1 = 5"
```

or just type aphostrope before it (')

```
'5*1 = 5
```

or put it between quotation marks:

```
 (5 & " * " & A1 & " = 5")
```